# python schema validation issue

Tags: python-3.x, validation, schema, pytest

I am trying to write a pytest case to say that there is clinical_in in the first place from the example below.  I have written this in pycharm and can run a test to say that in "clinical_in" has "code_tbl" and that equals "code" but cant seem to find a way to write a test case to say that clinical_in is there in the first place because there is no reason to go forward if it is not

how I am getting to the file is by reading it

```
json = json.load(open(resources_path + 'clinical_in.json'))
```

here is an example of my json

```
{
  "clinical_in": {
    "code_tbl": "code",
    "prov_tbl": "prov",
    "patient_tbl": {
      "patient_tbl":"patient_table",
      "filter": {
        "case1":{"data_typ":"Med", "claim_typ":["r", "s"]}
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: `assert 'clinical_in' in json.keys()`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all we need to ensure that json is in correct order. You should use OrderDict
Then we can write an assert

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
json_file = """{
  "clinical_in": {
    "code_tbl": "code",
    "prov_tbl": "prov",
    "patient_tbl": {
      "patient_tbl":"patient_table",
      "filter": {
        "case1": {"data_typ":"Med", "claim_typ":["r", "s"]}
      }
      }
    }
}"""
data = json.loads(json_file, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
assert list(data.keys())[0] == 'clinical_in'
```

Comment: i put that in and i am getting this error

E   json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 17 (char 16)

Comment: I also just made some changes which fixed that but now i am getting 

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: could you provide line?

Comment: this is the latest i am at 

import json
from collections import OrderedDict
def test_clinical_schema():
    json_data_diag = """ {"code_tbl": "icd","prov_tbl": "provider","patient_hub": {"patient_hub_tbl":"pat_provider_diag","filter": {"case1":{"data_typ_cd":"DX", "claim_typ_cd":["P", "I"]} }}}"""
    data = json.loads(json_data_diag, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    print (data.keys)
    assert list(OrderedDict.keys(data)) == ["clinical_input"]

i am getting this assertion error 
E         - ['code_tbl', 'prov_tbl', 'patient_hub']
E         + ['clinical_input']

Comment: it is again giving me back what clinical input has ... not that it is the key

Comment: actually i just figured it out ... you're the man Rafal, thank you for the help to me get me here.